# ASP.Net Identity Logout

Tags: .net, asp.net-identity

How to logout an user logged in with the ASP.Net Identity system?

I tried:

```
Authentication.SignOut();
```

But if I use this and then call an API marked with `[Authorize]` (adding the token as an header) It still returns me the data (instead of Unauthorized).

Comment: Did you add specific users or groups that can use this resource?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to call `SignOut` on the `AuthenticationManager` which you can get from the `OWIN context`.

```
var AuthenticationManager= HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
```

Comment: just a quick fix: it should include `Current`:   `HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication`

Comment: If you're inside an ASP.NET MVC controller you've got an instance property `HttpContext` from the base class, so you don't need `HttpContext.Current` in that scenario.

Comment: @MatthewWalton true, but if you are in let's say your custom HttpModule, then you certainly need `HttpContext.Current`...

Comment: HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie); would be more appropriate

Comment: Presumably this is pre .Net Core. Any idea how to do it in Core?

Comment: @Auspex you could try to call HttpContext.SignOutAsync()

Comment: @Auspex just tried out some methods, in my case the SignOutAsync() Method of the SingInManager class worked

Comment: @Seb Yeah, I figured it out eventually, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case, because i had `Authorize` attribute in my `AccountController` with admin role at class level i had to put `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute to my logout method. May be a solution to you too.

Comment: you could get an exception if an anonymous user tried to logout having the url. You should make a role only as a flag to a logged user. Same role to index logged user.