# Asp.net identity Logout not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I have tried every way possible, but I am still not able to logout the current user.
Currently I have the following code:

```
_authenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        string sKey = (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["user"];
        string sUser = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Cache[sKey]);
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove(sUser);
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
```

After this, the session is still not cleared.
Any ideas?

Authentication startup:

```
  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
           {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        });
```

SignIn Code:

```
    public override ApplicationUser Handle([NotNull]LoginCommand command)
    {
        var user = _userManager.Find(command.Login, command.Password);
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new RentalApplicationValidationException("No valid login");
        }

        _authenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        var identity = _userManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        _authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, identity);

        return user;
    }
```

Comment: what is your sign-in code look like? and Authentication startup configuration?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. See edit in my post.

Comment: Actual `SignOut` looks OK, but you are talking about session. Identity does not use session for authentication, only cookies. Do you have other code that uses session for auth?

Comment: No, I am not using it anywhere else. What is noticed is when I trigger the signout method directly in my Controller, everything works. When triggering the signout method from my command, it's not working.

Comment: This last statement points that `IAuthenticationManager` is resolved in the wrong lifescope - I have just noticed your comment below. Try registering `IAuthenticationManager` as `InstancePerDependency()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but is still not working in the command.
When requesting it the same way via a Controller, it does work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.Net Identity Logout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681726/asp-net-identity-logout)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `SignOut` within the `AuthenticationManager` I see you are trying above but are you getting it from the `Owin context`

try the below at the end of your code.

```
var authetication = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
authentication.SignOut();
```

Another way is to clear the cookie (i have seen again you tried this above but try it with just the AuthCookie) by setting the year by `-1`.. it seems when you `Session.Abandon()` the cookie is still there and same with `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()`.. try something like this at the end of your code:

```
HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
authCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
```

Comment: I am using autofac to register all managers from Asp.net identity like this:
    builder.Register(c =>      HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication)
                .As<IAuthenticationManager>()
                .InstancePerRequest();

When I resolve this in my command, I am not able to logout.
When I request the authenticatonmanager via GetOwinContext in my controller directly, it works. How can I make it work in my command?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call

`HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);`